# OpenGL (2.1 or greater) on Oracle VirtualBox?

Tags: drivers, 13.10, nvidia, virtualbox, windows-8

I need to run the Corona SDK, but I'm running Ubuntu (13.10), so I installed the W8 as guest on the VirtualBox.

I am struggling to make it work, because the Corona SDK states the following when I run it:

```
This machine does not meet the Corona Simulator's minimum video hardware requirements.

Minimum OpenGL version required: 2.1
Your machine's OpenGL version: 1.1.0
```

I tried to upgrade the video card's drivers, but I can't find the right drivers.
The Windows' Device Manager shows that it has a "VirtualBox Graphics Adapter for Windows 8", and I actually have a NVIDIA GeForce 740M (notebook) installed.

Is there a way to make my Corona SDK run?

Comment: AFAIK Virtualbox supports openGL 2.0 only. Have you installed the guest additions?. Have you activated direct3d support?.

Comment: OpenGL 2.1 support was [added in Virtual Box 3.2.0](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog-3.2).

Comment: @JavierRivera, I've installed the guest additions and enabled 2D&3D acceleration. What else can it be?

Comment: The F1 help says: _3D acceleration with Windows guests requires Windows 2000, Windows XP, Vista or Windows 7. Both OpenGL and Direct3D 8/9 (not with Windows 2000) are supported (experimental)_. It doesn't say which OpenGL ver, tho. I'll just install the W7 here and try again, brb

Comment: There is a special driver to make aero work, if it's enabled normal 3d acceleration don't work. Make sure it is disable, it's called WMD or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, OpenGL doesn't work on Windows 8 guests yet.
I"ve installed Windows 7; according to GLView, my OpenGL version is `2.1 Chromium 1` now.

The Corona SDK's Welcome Screen isn't getting rendered, though. I'll look into it, and if I need further assitance, I'll ask again.

Comment: If anyone is interested, I've asked it on the CoronaLabs Forum: http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/46438-running-sdk-on-virtualbox-welcome-screen-not-rendered/
According to a Corona Staff on this thread, "Corona SDK isn't supported in virtual machines".